# How do I efficiently use numpy to iterate through an array under some conditions to find patterns?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, iteration

Suppose I have a simply one dimensional array like:

[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]

I want to know the most efficient, or rather, fastest way using numpy to find the indexes where a certain pattern ends. The pattern I want to find consists of two parts. The first part includes everything until at least an nth number of consecutive 1s is found (let's say 3 for this threshold). After that, the pattern should be deemed to finish after another nth (let's say 3 again) consecutive 0s are found. When the happens, the index where the pattern ends should be stored in an array for later use.

I may have not described it well, so here's some code that does what I want with that same array above.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0])

patternFound = False
threshold = 3
nonzerosCount = 0
zerosCount = 0
split_indexes=[]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if patternFound:
        if arr[i] <= 0:
            zerosCount += 1
        else:
            zerosCount = 0

        if zerosCount >= threshold and i+1 != len(arr):
            zerosCount = 0
            patternFound=False
            split_indexes.append(i+1)
    else:
        if arr[i] >= 1:
            nonzerosCount += 1
        else:
            nonzerosCount = 0

        if nonzerosCount >= threshold:
            nonzerosCount = 0
            patternFound = True

print "Indexes:",  split_indexes            
print "Split:", 
for arr in np.split(arr, split_indexes):
    print arr,',',
```

The result is:

Indexes: [15, 35]
Split: [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0] , [0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0] , [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0] ,

This is fine for small arrays like the one in my example. However, I want to know more efficient ways to do this using numpy. For example, if I just wanted to sum a larger array

```
arr = np.random.uniform(size=1000000)
```

and I just iterated through it with:

```
total = 0
for i in arr:
    total += i
```

It is much slower than:

```
np.sum(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps for speed but you could try to use:

```
np.logical_or(np.logical_or(arr[:-2], arr[1:-1]), arr[2:])
```

to detect 3 consecutive `0` (look for `False`)

and

```
np.logical_and(np.logical_and(arr[:-2], arr[1:-1]), arr[2:])
```

to detect 3 consecutive `1` (look for `True`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io) to automatically turn your code into a native efficient version (explicitly iterating over NumPy array elements is a performance bottleneck).

Something like:

```
#pythran export pattern(bool [])
import numpy as np
def pattern(arr):
    patternFound = False
    threshold = 3
    nonzerosCount = 0
    zerosCount = 0
    split_indexes=[]

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if patternFound:
            if arr[i] <= 0:
                zerosCount += 1
            else:
                zerosCount = 0

            if zerosCount >= threshold and i+1 != len(arr):
                zerosCount = 0
                patternFound=False
                split_indexes.append(i+1)
        else:
            if arr[i] >= 1:
                nonzerosCount += 1
            else:
                nonzerosCount = 0

            if nonzerosCount >= threshold:
                nonzerosCount = 0
                patternFound = True
    split_indexes = np.asarray(split_indexes)
    return split_indexes, np.split(arr, split_indexes)
```

Compiled with `pythran pattern.py`.
Works just fine.

Without Pythran:

```
% python -m timeit -s 'import pattern, numpy; arr = numpy.asarray(numpy.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000000), dtype=bool)' 'pattern.pattern(arr)'
10 loops, best of 3: 3.11 sec per loop
```

With Pythran:

```
% python -m timeit -s 'import pattern, numpy; arr = numpy.asarray(numpy.random.choice([0, 1], size=100000), dtype=bool)' 'pattern.pattern(arr)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 880 usec per loop
```